# Basic Groovy query regarding security / visibility

Tags: security, grails, gsp

I am building a .gsp page to list the user details of an application with their specifications.

I want to let 3 roles to view it but allow only admin role to save any changes they make. For this I want the save button to be visible on screen only when the admin logs in.

I know I should be handling this in the controller, but being very new to programming I have no idea how that can be achieved?

Even if you could point me to a link that explains this it would be helpful.

Comment: Tag changed to Grails, as I assume that's what you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is with Grails?

You really shouldnt invent your own security layer, the possibilities for getting it wrong are huge.  Have a look at the [spring-core-security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

It has [detailed documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) (and for the bit in your question when you get it all set up, [the documentation is here)](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib)

There are also tutorials to be found all over the web ([one is here](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/))